# Breeze Save - Error: CROSS APPLY is not supported by Oracle

Tags: breeze

I am saving a complex object graph from breeze, and I get the following error from the server:

Error: CROSS APPLY is not supported by Oracle

We are using an Oracle database using Devart provider. From my research, it seems that the only solution to this problem is to avoid certain linq query expressions. These threads provide further context:

http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=18849

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/ae826dd9-1bab-4f64-a7ee-f082a2177346/

The last thread linked is particularly disheartening, as this appears to be a Microsoft-related EF issue on which they have gone dark on for quite some time.

Since the only remedy for this appears to be avoiding specific linq operators/expressions, I must ask if there is any way to use breeze and avoid these offending linq expressions? If not, I am lead to conclude that breeze is currently limited only to relational databases that are fully-supported by EF, which from the my research is effectively only MS SQL.

Hoping I am wrong,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Breeze's EFContextProvider then you are limited to using an EF backend.  However you do some other options.  The first is that you can pass your own parameters into your controller methods, ( see the EntityQuery.withParameters method).  This may allow you to rewrite your expression on the server to avoid EF expressions that cannot be tranlated properly for Oracle.

In addition, you can use Breeze with your own custom context provider or you can take over the server side completely.  The first is a good approach if you are talking to another .NET backend, the second is appropriate when you are talking to an arbitrary non .NET backend.

We are planning on releasing an NHibernate backend to breeze as well as a Node-MongoDb backend within the next few weeks to illustrate both of these.